# Add file date to file name in bash

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I'm looking for a programmatic way to add a file's date to the filename. I'm on a Mac, Yosemite (10.10).

Using Bash, I have put a fair amount of effort into this, but just too new to get there so far. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

#!/bin/bash

(IFS='
'
for x in `ls -l | awk '{print$9" "$7"-"$6"-"$9}'`
do 
    currentfilename=$(expr "$x" : '\($substring\)')
    filenamewithdate=$(expr "$x" : '.*\($substring\)')
    echo "$currentfilename"
    echo "$filenamewithdate"
done)
```

The idea here is to capture detailed ls output, use awk to capture the strings for the columns with the filename ($9), and also date fields ($7 and $6), then loop that output to capture the previous filename and new filename with the date to mv the file from old filename to new. The awk statement adds a space to separate current filename from new. The echo statement is there now to test if I am able to parse the awk ouput. I just don't know what to add for $substring to get the parts of the string that are needed.

I have much more to learn about Bash scripting, so I hope you'll bear with me as I learn. Any guidance?

Thanks.

Comment: for starters, if you don't know how to use `man programOfInterest`, you need to. Then, use `man stat`. You should be able to construct a better dated filename  using `printf` options of `stat`. Your use of `for x in ls ...` should be replaced with `for f in *; do newFName=$(stat "$f" ...opts to stat) ; ....; done`. Don't use `ls` in a for loop, it's a bad habit to get into. This will get you thinking about your problem if a different way. Update your Q or delete this and post a new Q to help clarify your problem. Good luck.

Comment: To elaborate more on @shelter's comment: Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. *Globs* are much more simple AND correct: 
Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: don't use linux tag if you're coding on Yosemite. I don't have a Mac so it's possible that `stat` isn't available (I hope not!). If not, your `awk` code will need to allow for cases where file date is more than six months olds, where the value of `$8` changes for time-stamp, to a year value. Good luck.

Comment: Finally, you don't need two `#!/bin/bash` lines in your file AND `$substring` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in your file. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [`stat` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html), you'd want:

```
for file in *; do
    filedate=$(stat -t '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' -f '%m' "$file")
    newfile="$file-$filedate"
    echo "current: $file -> new: $newfile"
done
```

Adjust your preferred datetime format to your taste.

You could save a line with

```
for file in *; do
    newfile=$(stat -t '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' -f '%N-%m' "$file")
```